# Java - ExecutorService : How to re run "wait state" thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice, executor

I'm using ExecutorService like,

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++){
    executorService.submit(new MyRunnable());
}
```

and my Runnable is like,

```
@Override
public void run(){
    while(true){
        try{
            Data data = SynchronizedQueue.getData(); // Class Name is Sample...
            if( data != null ){
                //process with data
            }else{
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I break from Runnable's while-loop, the Thread's state change to "wait".

Q1. Can my "while(true) loop" die?

Q2. If it's able to die, how to re-run?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you break from while loop, your thread will go to state TERMINATED since it will reach end of function.

A1. Your while loop will die

A2. You cannot. You should submit your runnable to executorService again.

Comment: is it equal wait and terminated?

Comment: WAIT means : A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.

Comment: I guess your Runnable goes to WAIT state at "SynchronizedQueue.getData()" this call

Comment: No... I add to while-loop "break;" and It changed "WAIT"

Comment: About A1 : If I don't break loop, would it be okay?

Comment: If you do not break loop, while loop will never die